# how to formally show the question below

Tags: analysis, algorithms

Show that $0.1n + 10\sqrt n$ is not $O(\sqrt n)$ using the definition of big-$O$ only.

This is what I've tired: 
$0.1n + 10\sqrt n \neq O(\sqrt n)$ 
$0.1n + 10\sqrt n = 0.1n + 10n^{\frac12}$ 
$f(n) = 0.1n + 10\sqrt n$ 
$g(n) = \sqrt n$

and I got stuck here

Comment: What is your definition of big-$O$? Which is greater: $n$ or $\sqrt{n}$?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose for sake of contradiction that $0.1 n + 10 \sqrt{n}$ *were* indeed $O(\sqrt{n})$. Then there would exist some constant $C$ such that $0.1 n + 10 \sqrt{n} \le C \sqrt{n}$ for all large $n$.

However, if you divide both sides of that inequality by $\sqrt{n}$, then
$$\frac{0.1 n + 10 \sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}} = 0.1 \sqrt{n} + 10 \to \infty$$
as $n \to \infty$, so no such constant $C$ exists.